# IntelliSense errors while rebuilding application in Angular 2.0.0 version

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, rxjs

I am trying to rebuild application with latest Angular 2.0.0 version and everything works fine except that there are some intellisense errors in observables. Is this an issue with rxjs module where the error is throwing in Catch.d.ts, how can i get rid of these error:

[image]